# How to check that a dictionary / collection can be iterated over?

Tags: c#, linq

I have some code that works on a dictionary and Using simple linq functions to find some key values within the dictionary however recently I am getting the following error ...

```
InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object
System.Linq.Enumerable.Iterate[KeyValuePair`2,Int32] (IEnumerable`1 source, Int32 initValue, System.Func`3 selector)
```

How do I confirm that the operation is safe to be carried out and thus avoid this error?

Code sample causing the problem ...

```
public void UpdateBounds()
{
    lock (Voxels)
    {
            Start = new IntVector3(Voxels.Min(v => v.Key.X), Voxels.Min(v => v.Key.Y), Voxels.Min(v => v.Key.Z));
            End = new IntVector3(Voxels.Max(v => v.Key.X), Voxels.Max(v => v.Key.Y), Voxels.Max(v => v.Key.Z));
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using a `ConcurrentDictionary` instead, as it is thread safe. Good question though.

Comment: I need performance in this case the dictionary contains voxel information that I fast random access to. Concurrent Dictionaries as I understand introduce overhead ... I thought I could simple do lock(context) { access dictionary } but this doesnt appear to solve my problem.

Comment: If you need performance for your application (I guess using voxels, you're doing some image processing), I wouldn't use linq.  Neither executing 6 linq operation to find min / max values.  
You should use only 1 loop testing each value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're doing an operation on an empty Dictionary object.

Check if it contains anything before executing that statement. `Dictionary.Count` is your guy.

Comment: that'll do it ... msdn seems to agree that this will happen if nothing in the dictionary.

Comment: If the `IEnumerable` is empty `Min` and `Max` both throw `InvalidOperationException` with a message of "Sequence contains no elements."